# Nationhood of Nepal and Bhutan, in Indian subcontinent

Tags: india

During the period around Independence,  India, under Sardar Vallabh Bhai Patel's programme to unite the subcontinent, was getting Princely states to accede to Union of India. There were around 570 Princely States. Then why were Nepal and Bhutan, considered , and accepted separate nations, and not just another princely state?

Comment: Possibly a better fit for http://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question has been posted on [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/19274/8066) as suggested by Relaxed.

Comment: Should I answer this question, if it has been answered there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question has already been answered on [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/19274/nationhood-of-bhutan-and-nepal-in-indian-subcontinent)